# `cat /proc/kmsg` outputs broken text

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-messages, dmesg

`cat /proc/kmsg` is convenient way to follow kernel messages. But the output is unreliable. Example:

```
< eoyfl-o-ilF ilaltssI hwflssesJ a hwbctaealatv-psL hwmmr-sg()nc-l-TtssN oeOfso-eitr()so-l-iesQ na ycso-aksae()Umutfref()so-lce-ak()Wiet_e_yr upfrc-ufrZ <6>[640655.817496] SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reBoot Crash terminate-all-tasks(E) memory-full-oom-kill(F) kill-all-tasks(I) thaw-filesystems(J) saK show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(L) show-memory-usage(M) nice-all-RT-tasks(N) powerOff show-registers(P) show-all-timers(Q) unRaw Sync show-task-states(T) Unmount force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(W) Write_to_dev_sysrq dump-ftrace-buffer(Z)
```

(I pressed Alt+Sysrq+h thrice: first time it printed broken text without newline. Second time it printed correct text. Third time it has just exited (EOF).

What am I doing wrong? How to follow kernel messages (without dependence of various sysklogd and config files and `tail -f`).

Alternatively, how to use klogd to just print messages (like `cat /proc/kmsg` but correct) without any syslogs or `klogd: Already running`)?

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783630/how-to-monitor-the-syslogprintk-in-a-lkm

Comment: Also, this web page indicates that it's a ring buffer, so "tail -f" and friends might not work so well anyway (use "dmesg" instead although that won't monitor like "tail -f" can):  http://www.techpulp.com/blog/tag/prockmsg/

Comment: Starting with Linux 3.5, a new `/dev/kmsg` interface has been implemented, which allows multiple processes to read the kernel log without corruption, and `cat /dev/kmsg` will automatically follow new entries. (*util-linux* 2.22 also implements `dmesg --follow`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that output of `cat /proc/kmsg` is garbled because there may be other consumers of kernel logging data, like syslogd and friends. For me, output characters get interleavingly to cat or syslogd (tried on Ubuntu 12.04). See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477776/496009

I may imagine, `cat /proc/kmsg` would work reliably when booted into a pristine system (for example, kernel booted with `init=/bin/sh` argument). Otherwise, using `dmesg` command to read kernel log is expectedly easier.

Comment: Is there a dmesg which prints all messages continuously (expect of `watch "dmesg | tail"`)?

Comment: @Vi.: If you run Linux kernel ≥ 3.5, you should be able to do `cat /dev/kmsg` or even `dmesg --follow` (requires util-linux ≥ 2.22). On older systems, your only choice is to `tail -f` the syslog files in `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem `cat /proc/kmsg` exiting prematurely due to it trying to display unprintable characters.

I have found that:

```
cat -v /proc/kmsg
```

removes all the unprintable characters from the output and prevents `cat` from exiting prematurely.

Comment: I don't think it's because of those characters.